# finding common superclass and length of path in class hierarchies

Tags: rdf, sparql, owl, dbpedia

I have two classes, A and B, from DBpedia. How can I calculate the distance (number of edges) from each class to a common superclass C, and how can I find this common superclass?

Answer (score 4):

You can do this, but a couple of things should be noted first:

1. Two classes may have lots of superclasses in common, not necessarily just one.  This means that there may not be a unique most specialized common superclass.
2. If some class C is a superclass of A and B, then every superclass of C is *also* a superclass of A and B.
3. A class D might be a superclass of C by multiple paths, which can cause some difficulties if you're trying to compute length.  E.g.,

   ```
   Computer Hardware
     Monitors
       Flatscreen Monitors
         Dell Flatscreen Monitors  *
     Dell Hardware
       Dell Flatscreen Monitors    *
   ```

   In this hierarchy, Dell Flatscreen Monitors is a subclass of Computer Hardware by a path of length 2 (DFM → DH → CH) and by a path of length 3 (DFM → FM → M →CH).  That's fine, but if you're computing a length from DFM to another subclass of CH, which of those should you use?
4. There might not be any common superclasses in the data.  This is also a perfectly legal situation.  Now, *in OWL*, every class is a subclass `owl:Thing`, but that doesn't hold for RDF in general, and you probably won't even get that result from DBpedia because there's no OWL reasoner attached.

Assuming that you can work out the details that you need to address those issues, this isn't too hard.  It's easiest, in my opinion, to build up this query step by step.  First, using a query like this, you can get the superclasses of a class, and the length of the path to each of the superclasses.  This does presume that there is a unique path from the subclass to the superclass.  If there are multiple paths, I think the length reported will be the sum of the different paths.  I'm not sure how you could get around this.

```
select ?sub ?super (count(?mid) as ?length) where {
  values ?sub { dbpedia-owl:Person } 
  ?sub rdfs:subClassOf* ?mid .
  ?mid rdfs:subClassOf+ ?super .
}
group by ?sub ?super
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql/?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=select%20?sub%20?super%20%28count%28?mid%29%20as%20?length%29%20where%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20values%20?sub%20%7B%20dbpedia-owl%3aPerson%20%7D%20%0D%0A%20%20?sub%20rdfs%3asubClassOf%2a%20?mid%20.%0D%0A%20%20?mid%20rdfs%3asubClassOf%2b%20?super%20.%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Agroup%20by%20?sub%20?super&format=text/html&timeout=30000&debug=on)

```
sub                                super                               length
http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Person http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Agent   1
http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Person http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Thing 2
```

Now the trick is to use this approach for both the subclasses, and then join the results based on the superclasses that they have in common, using a query like this:

```
select * 
{
  values (?a ?b) { (dbpedia-owl:Person dbpedia-owl:SportsTeam) }

  { select ?a ?super (count(?mid) as ?aLength) { 
      ?a rdfs:subClassOf* ?mid .
      ?mid rdfs:subClassOf+ ?super .
    }
    group by ?a ?super
  }
  { select ?b ?super (count(?mid) as ?bLength) { 
      ?b rdfs:subClassOf* ?mid .
      ?mid rdfs:subClassOf+ ?super .
    }
    group by ?b ?super
  }
}
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql/?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=select%20%2a%20%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%20%20values%20%28?a%20?b%29%20%7B%20%28dbpedia-owl%3aPerson%20dbpedia-owl%3aSportsTeam%29%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%7B%20select%20?a%20?super%20%28count%28?mid%29%20as%20?aLength%29%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20?a%20rdfs%3asubClassOf%2a%20?mid%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20?mid%20rdfs%3asubClassOf%2b%20?super%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20group%20by%20?a%20?super%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%7B%20select%20?b%20?super%20%28count%28?mid%29%20as%20?bLength%29%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20?b%20rdfs%3asubClassOf%2a%20?mid%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20?mid%20rdfs%3asubClassOf%2b%20?super%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20group%20by%20?b%20?super%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D&format=text/html&timeout=30000&debug=on)

That query still finds the path lengths for *all* the common superclasses, not just most specific ones, and it's still not adding the length from `?a` to `?super` and the length from `?b` to `?super` to get the full path length.  That's just a bit of arithmetic though.  You can order these results by the length, and then limit to just one result so that you're getting the shortest one.  As I pointed out, there might not be a unique most specific common subclasses, but the result with the shortest length will be *one* of the most specific common subclasses.

```
select ?a ?b ?super (?aLength + ?bLength as ?length)
{
  values (?a ?b) { (dbpedia-owl:Person dbpedia-owl:SportsTeam) }

  { select ?a ?super (count(?mid) as ?aLength) { 
      ?a rdfs:subClassOf* ?mid .
      ?mid rdfs:subClassOf+ ?super .
    }
    group by ?a ?super
  }
  { select ?b ?super (count(?mid) as ?bLength) { 
      ?b rdfs:subClassOf* ?mid .
      ?mid rdfs:subClassOf+ ?super .
    }
    group by ?b ?super
  }
}
order by ?length
limit 1
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql/?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=select%20?a%20?b%20?super%20%28?aLength%20%2b%20?bLength%20as%20?length%29%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%20%20values%20%28?a%20?b%29%20%7B%20%28dbpedia-owl%3aPerson%20dbpedia-owl%3aSportsTeam%29%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%7B%20select%20?a%20?super%20%28count%28?mid%29%20as%20?aLength%29%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20?a%20rdfs%3asubClassOf%2a%20?mid%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20?mid%20rdfs%3asubClassOf%2b%20?super%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20group%20by%20?a%20?super%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%7B%20select%20?b%20?super%20%28count%28?mid%29%20as%20?bLength%29%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20?b%20rdfs%3asubClassOf%2a%20?mid%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20?mid%20rdfs%3asubClassOf%2b%20?super%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20group%20by%20?b%20?super%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aorder%20by%20?length%0D%0Alimit%201&format=text/html&timeout=30000&debug=on)

```
a      b          super length
Person SportsTeam Agent 3
```

Comment: I want the FIRST common superclass!

Comment: @user2837896 I'm putting the query together now, but note that  there may not be a single most-specific common superclass.  There can be multiple most-specific superclasses.

Comment: I understand. But How can I do to calculate this if the classes are referenced by different namaspaces? for example http://dbpedia.org/ontology/NameOfTheClass_A and http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/NameOfTheClass_B ?

Comment: the distance between 
http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/PeopleFromSantiago
and
http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Writer
from the first common superclass. How can I do it?

Comment: The namespace doesn't have anything to do with it.  The [predefined namespace declarations](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?nsdecl) allow you to write `yago:PeopleFromSantiago` for one and `dbpedia-owl:Writer` for the other.

Comment: But I won't be able to calculate the distance between yago:PeopleFromSantiago and dbpedia-owl:Writer...I have no result if I use your query with yago:PeopleFromSantiago and dbpedia-owl:Writer

Comment: @user2837896 But even though you can easily _write_ those resources in the SPARQL query doesn't mean that DBpedia has integrated their class hierarchies in such a way that they have _any_ common superclasses at all.  In fact, those classes don't, as you can check with a query asking whether there are any common superclasses of `yago:PeopleFromSantiago` and `dbpedia-owl:Writer`: `ask { ?a ^rdfs:subClassOf* yago:PeopleFromSantiago, dbpedia-owl:Writer }`.  It returns `false`, because there are no common superclasses.

Comment: @user2837896 That's right;  According to DBpedia, there are no common superclasses of those two classes.  Was there some preëxisting reason or unstated assumption to reason to assume that they'd have a common superclass?

Comment: If I Have http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/ChileanFootballers  and dbpedia.org/ontology/SoccerPlayer, these classes should be related..they represent both FootballPlayer ! Instead they haven't any superclasses in common..This problem is important for me

Comment: @user2837896 I can certainly see why you'd expect there to be individuals that are members of both, but why would there need to be any superclasses?  The DBpedia classes are from [this ontology](http://mappings.dbpedia.org/server/ontology/classes/).  The Yago classes and hierarchy is defined to aid in interoperability with the Yago vocabulary.  There's no reason to assume that someone added `rdfs:subClassOf` links between classes from the two hierarchies.  Indeed, that's a very difficult thing to do, because the class definitions may be very subtle.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor could you update your SPARQL scripts based on their most recent version. They don't seem to be working anymore.