# Find the most precise common superclasses between two items

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I would like to find the first common superclass(es) between several Wikidata entities.

Let's take a [bridge](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q12280) and a [cemetery](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q39614). What is their "smallest" common superclass?

- A bridge is a subclass of "architectural structure".
- A cemetery is a subclass of "place of worship", which is a subclass of "architectural structure".

---> Their most specialized common class is "architectural structure".

[This Sparql query](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fclasse%20%3FclasseLabel%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%0Awd%3AQ12280%20wdt%3AP279%2A%20%3Fclasse%20.%0AFILTER%20%20EXISTS%20%7B%20wd%3AQ39614%20wdt%3AP279%2A%20%3Fclasse%20.%7D%0A%20%20%0A%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22%5BAUTO_LANGUAGE%5D%2Cen%22.%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%7D%0A) is close to the solution :

```
SELECT ?classe ?classeLabel WHERE {

wd:Q12280 wdt:P279* ?classe .
FILTER  EXISTS { wd:Q39614 wdt:P279* ?classe .}

 SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }

}
```

Problem: it returns all common classes between both items, not just the first ones. How could I filter the answer to get what I want?

Comment: Well, your query doesn't reflect in any sense the definition of *Least Common Subsumer*(LCV) You're simply querying for all superclasses `A` of `bridge` and `for all superclasses `B` of `cemetery` and then you return classes contained in `A` and `B`. You should check the definition of LCS and see which other condition is necessary.

Comment: Least Common Subsumer is certainly the phrase I was looking for, but I did not know it existed and could not search Google effectively.

Comment: Here we go: `SELECT ?classe ?classeLabel WHERE {
wd:Q12280 wdt:P279* ?classe .
wd:Q39614 wdt:P279* ?classe .
filter not exists { 
  ?otherClass wdt:P279 ?classe ;
                          ^wdt:P279* wd:Q12280, wd:Q39614 .
}
SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }        
}`

Comment: Note, there is not always a unique LCS!

Comment: Oh, thank you very much! But could you publish this query in an answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this question is of interest to someone else, here is the SPAQL query I finally use to get the Least common subsumers of more than two items. This is a mix between @AKSW response in comments and the answer to [that previous question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23510851/how-to-get-least-common-subsumer-in-ontology-using-sparql-query).

```
SELECT ?lcs ?lcsLabel WHERE {

    ?lcs ^wdt:P279* wd:Q32815, wd:Q34627, wd:Q16970, wd:Q16560 .
    filter not exists {
    ?sublcs ^wdt:P279* wd:Q32815, wd:Q34627, wd:Q16970, wd:Q16560 ;
          wdt:P279 ?lcs .
      }

      SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". } 
    }
```

[Try it.](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Flcs%20%3FlcsLabel%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%3Flcs%20%5Ewdt%3AP279%2A%20wd%3AQ32815%2C%20wd%3AQ34627%2C%20wd%3AQ16970%2C%20wd%3AQ16560%20.%0A%20%20%20%20filter%20not%20exists%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fsublcs%20%5Ewdt%3AP279%2A%20wd%3AQ32815%2C%20wd%3AQ34627%2C%20wd%3AQ16970%2C%20wd%3AQ16560%20%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20wdt%3AP279%20%3Flcs%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22%5BAUTO_LANGUAGE%5D%2Cen%22.%20%7D%20%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)