# Common super category between two wikipedia categories using DBpedia

Tags: sparql, jena, wikipedia, dbpedia

I have the following SPARQL query that supposed to retrieve the common categroies between Category:Computer_science category and Category:German_scientists

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?subject WHERE {
?subject <http://purl.org/dc/terms/subject> ?cat1, ?cat2 .
?cat1 skos:broader? / skos:broader? / skos:broader?         
  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Computer_science> .     
?cat2 skos:broader? / skos:broader? / skos:broader?
  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:German_scientists>.
} LIMIT 10
```

I need to get the closest category to them or who has the shortest path to both categories , How Can I do that ? How to get the lenght between each common categroy between (computer_science) and (German_scientists)  for example ?

Comment: I'm confused, how is the query (that retrieves articles that are in subcategories of both categories, which is not what you claim it does) related to your question about supercategories?

Comment: Instead of retrieving the articles common between them, I need to retrieve the super category between them and the length to each category in case they have many.
I may rewrite the question.

Comment: Take a look at the results for [\[sparql\] common superclass](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsparql%5D+common+superclass).  I think you may find a solution, although you may need to replace some rdfs:subClassOf with skos:broader.

Comment: **"I need to get the closest category to them or who has the shortest path to both categories"** Can you clarify?  What if the lengths are 2 and 2 versus another concept with distances 3 and 1?

Comment: I find what I want on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19680440/finding-common-superclass-and-length-of-path-in-class-hierarchies/19681697#19681697
thank you , but it can not process the query :
Virtuoso 42000 Error TN...: Exceeded 1000000000 bytes in transitive temp memory.  How to fix this ? , I am using jena

Comment: Yes, the DBpedia endpoint has some limitations;  that's why I went with the `{0,4}` approach in my question.  If you've got a query that you think should work (aside from the Virtuoso transitive temp memory issue), please add it to the question.  It will make your question a bit more specific, and as it stands now, we don't know what the *actual* query that you get the warning for is.

Answer (score 3):

Virtuoso, the endpoint that serves the DBpedia data supports a non-standard SPARQL extension to property paths:  instead of just `p*`, `p+`, and `p?`, to mean a path of length "zero or more", "one or more", and "zero or one", respectively, Virtuoso also supports `p{m,n}`, meaning a path of length "at least m and at most n".  By trying the following query with n=0 and increasing values of m, I started getting results with m=4:

```sql
prefix category: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:>

select distinct ?super where {
  ?super (^skos:broader){0,4} category:Computer_science, category:German_scientists
}
```

```
super
-----------------------------------------------
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Technology
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Science
```

Comment: @dewet The query I posted works if you post it to the web interface at http://dbpedia.org/sparql  If you want to use the query somewhere else, you'll need to include the prefix.  Check the "namespace prefixes" link at the top right of that page.

Comment: I did thank you , but can you please check the comments for you on the question ?

Comment: @dewet Ah, I didn't see that comment;  if you put "@" followed by someone's name, they get a notification about the comment.

Comment: I can not specify property path in Jena API ,
 (^skos:broader){0,4} only works in endpoint.
@Joshua Taylor

Comment: @dewet yes, as i said, it's not actually legal sparql, it's an extension that virtuoso implements (it was in early drafts, though)

Comment: Is there any method that let me restrict the number of paths to super category ? It keeps shows HttpException: 500 in my program

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Hi Joshua... I tried to run the above query..Now the query do not work....Can you please explain?

Comment: @riturajsinghrathore  what does "do not work" mean?  Does it produce an error? Does it produce results different from what you're expecting? Something else...?

Comment: @rituraj you may be talking about the "Virtuoso 37000 Error SP030: SPARQL compiler, line 4: Undefined namespace prefix at 'category' before ','" error.  The dbpedia public Sparql endpoint changed some of their [predefined namespace prefixes](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?help=nsdecl). It looks like category: should be dbc: now.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Thank you for the quick reply. Indeed, you are right. Thanks for

Answer (score 0):

For the clarification:: The query is the PREFIX version of the below answer which follows current norms :

```
PREFIX dbpedia: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
PREFIX dcterms: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>
PREFIX dbc: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:>
select distinct ?super where {
  ?super (^skos:broader){0,4} dbc:Computer_science, dbc:German_scientists
}
```

[SPARQL RESULTS](https://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=PREFIX%20dbpedia%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20dcterms%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fpurl.org%2Fdc%2Fterms%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20dbc%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FCategory%3A%3E%0D%0Aselect%20distinct%20%3Fsuper%20where%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%3Fsuper%20%28%5Eskos%3Abroader%29%7B0%2C4%7D%20dbc%3AComputer_science%2C%20dbc%3AGerman_scientists%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on&run=%20Run%20Query%20)

```
super
--------------------------------------------
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Science_and_technology
```